# How can i optimize this network

Tags: network

I got a router on a stick and I want to optimize it by reducing its cost and also the configuration costs

This topology is to facilitate inter Vlan routing so Vlan1 can communicate with Vlan2. PC0 and PC1 are on vlan1 and PC2 and PC3 on Vlan2.

The question is how will this topology be optimized.

The topology is illustrated in the figure
[image: Topology of router on a stick]

Comment: You haven't provided any details, so it's impossible to give you a good answer.  How many VLANs?  Do you need more than one? What else do these devices connect to?
If you are going to reduce costs with two network devices, the only way to lower costs is to eliminate one of them.  Maybe you don't need a router.

Comment: Sorry forgive me I forgot mentioning vlans, ill update it

Comment: updated the question, sorry for the mistake!!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this network implemention devices required

`1) cisco2901/K9 router 2) C2960 24 port switch Use cat 6e cables for this connectivity`

Router costs 13000 inr+ switch costs 25000

Important Configuration:

`Router(config)# int f0/0 #no ip address   #no shutdown Router(config)#intf0/0.10 #encapsulation dot1q 10 Ip address 192.168.10.1 255.25&.255.0 #no shutdown`

`Router(config)#intf0/0.20 #encapsulation dot1q 20 #ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0 #no shutdown`

**You can have DHCP server on router**

`Router(config)#ip DHCP pool vlan 2 #network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0 #ip DHCP excluded address 192.168.10.1 #dns name server 8.8.8 8 Router(config)#ip DHCP pool vlan 3 #network 192 .168.20.0 255.255.255.0 #ip DHCP exculde address 192.168.20.1 #dns name server 8.8.8.8`

**Switch configuration**

Switch

`Switch(config)#vlan 2 #name production`

`Switch(config)# vlan 3 #nane UAT`

`Switch (config)#int ethernet 6/1 #switchport mode trunk #switchport trunk allowed vlan all #no shutdown`

`Switch(config)#int ethernet f0/1 #switchport mode access Switch access vlan 2 #no shutdown`
.
`Switch(config)#int ethernet F1/1 #switchport mode access #switchport access 3 #no shutdown`

**Configure remaining ports as per your requirement**

To optimise costs further you can use cisco router 1800 series integrated service router it's costs only 10000 inr

Note : don't use vlan 1 beacuse it is default vlan keep it as backup you can use in future if your network increase

You can also accomplish this setup by replacing c2950 switch with cisco3850 layer 3 switch and configuration svi (sub virtual interface ) and aslo you can configure DHCP for dynamic ip allocation and access -list to restrict traffic among vlans  and use router 1800 series as perimeter devices to get isp connected to outside interface and   configuration natting in router . configure default route in  layer3 385O switch pointing towards router inside interfàce and configure static route in router with destination as Lan subnets and pointing towards layer3 switch interface

But by using layer3 switch you can optimise network performance but cisco 385O Làyer3 switch costs your approximately 3 lakhs INR..or else your can check  any other layer3 switch which suits your company budget..

Comment: Thanks man really appreciated but I want to tell you that I forgot the VLan part in my question, can you pls review it again and then answer, sorry for the blunder :(

Answer (score 0):

Router-on-a-stick means you trunk all VLANs to Router-PT and route between them there.

Assuming the router or its downlink is a bottleneck, the easiest way to improve performance is to replace the L2 switch by an L3 switch. Configure VLAN interfaces at the switch (SVI) with IP addresses and activate routing between them. Point the switch's default route to Router-PT. Point the end nodes' default gateway to their respective VLAN's SVI.

The advantages of using a center L3 switch include:

- routing at wire speed
- removal of switch-router link bottleneck
- optimization of L2 hops between VLANs (two hops *node→switch→node* instead of four hops *node→switch→router→switch→node*)

Comment: can we use a multiswitch and replace the router and the switch?

Comment: Multi-*layer* switch? Layer-3 switches can't NAT, so you'd still need a router doing that.

Comment: oh but there is no need of it so ill stick with multi layer

Comment: Without requiring NAT or advanced router functions (filtering, tunneling, ...) you don't need a separate router at all.